# Linear Algebra quick question on inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I just have a quick question

How come =p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2) is an inner product but =p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)-p(3)q(3) is not?

Which axiom is being violated. And am i correct that that =p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2) is an inner product?

Comment: You've already asked this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710215/quick-question-on-showing-a-function-is-an-inner-product#comment1486461_710215)!

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are polynomials?

Comment: yea there are polynomials

Comment: i am trying to prove this with the identity axiom, scalar axiom, non negative axiom

Comment: "
  
 
The second product does not satisfy the parallelogram law so it is not an inner product" you already received a great answer

Comment: I haven't even learned the parallelogram law yet :/ The only things I have learned are the axioms i mentioned above

Comment: Let $p(x)=(x+2)^2$. Then your second inner product $p,p$ would be $0$ yet $(1,2,3)\neq 0$

Comment: In my last comment it should be $p(x)=x+2$ (not squared). That way it gives $p \cdot p = p(1)p(1)+p(2)p(2)-p(3)p(3)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

If your inner products are to be defined on the collection of polynomials, say with real coefficients, then as noted in a comment the second one fails because $p(x)=x+2$ is not the zero polynomial yet $p\cdot p=p(1)p(1)+p(2)p(2)-p(3)p(3)=3^2+4^2-5^2=0.$

But the first one also fails because $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$ is not the zero polynomial yet $p\cdot p = p(1)p(1)+p(2)p(2)=0\cdot 0 +0 \cdot 0 = 0.$

There may be hope for the first one if you restrict the polynomials to only their values at $1,2$ somehow, but in that case some care would need to be taken to define the space on which the inner product is supposed to be defined. There seems to be no problem with linearity in either factor of $p \cdot q$ for either of your proposed inner products, though.

Comment: yea, the first one only has values 1 and 2

Comment: Im basing my assumptions off http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html the 4  points

Comment: So are you really looking at the maps from $A=\{1,2\}$ into the reals which are obtained by restricting real polynomials to the set $A$?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean by your comment. I was just curious because all the example I see in the book of inner product functions have no negative signs